# How do I run a React app locally using npm serve

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, serve, craco

I have a React app and I want to serve a production build using the below script:

```json
    "serve": "serve -s build"
```

While the application loads with the above command, I cannot get the API calls to work. For example the calls to http://localhost:3000/api/users return the `index.html` instead of the JSON response.

Actually for the API calls, I have a `craco.config.js` as below:

```
  devServer: {
    static: 'src',
    hot: true,
    port: 3000,
    historyApiFallback: {
      disableDotRule: true
    },
    proxy: {
      '/api/**': {
        target: {
          port: 8080
        },
        secure: false
      }
    },
  },
```

With `serve`, how do I get these API calls to work? Is it somehow possible to have the APIs running on port 8080 and those work when running locally using `npm run serve`?

Comment: You could use an env to make a specific "prod for localhost" build that fetches from `localhost:8080`. Another option could be to have a reverse-proxy running locally that handles the redirection.

Comment: @super - Thanks...Are there any references I can check to understand better what you have mentioned about both the approaches ?

Comment: Also I do have env specific builds...but in this case, the call I have gets invoked from the UI itself as fetchFn("api/users", {}, "GET") and I want to somehow use the server on port 8080 like how I have shown via my craco.config.js

Comment: That _is_ how you serve a React app using `serve`. Returning the `index.html` is the whole point of the `-s` flag; that's how you make client-side routing work. The point of using a proxy for local dev is that it simulates the production topology where the app _can_ make relative requests (e.g. due to a reverse proxy, or just being served as static assets by the API server). If that's _not_ the case, then don't use the dev proxy.

Comment: `fetchFn(someVar + "api/users")` and `someVar` can be an empty string or `localhost:8080/` for the local test. As for reverse proxy, there is a multitude of them out there. I like nginx, but you could use any one really. Give it a rule to send `/api` to you api server, and anything else to the thing that serves your react build.